# How to transform a <ul> element into a DataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to transform this `<ul>` into a DataTable:

```
<ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> <p:graphicImage
                                name="images/child_M.png" library="ultima-layout" width="72" />
                            <span class="name">Joshua Williams</span> <span class="email">joshua@pf-ultima.com</span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> <p:graphicImage
                                name="images/child_M.png" library="ultima-layout" width="72" />
                            <span class="name">Emily Clark</span> <span class="email">emily@pf-ultima.com</span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> <p:graphicImage
                                name="images/child_F.png" library="ultima-layout" width="72" />
                            <span class="name">Susan Johnson</span> <span class="email">susan@pf-ultima.com</span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> <p:graphicImage
                                name="images/child_F.png" library="ultima-layout" width="72" />
                            <span class="name">Kelly Stark</span> <span class="email">kelly@pf-ultima.com</span>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
```

Where I want to replace the name and email values with the correct ones, that come from a list (from the value element of the Datatable).This `<ul>` element layout is very good, since the text is on the right, good font and the image on the left and I want to replicate it within a DataTable.

Comment: Why? If you like the layout why change it to another that you will have to tweak to be the same as this, when you already have this?

Comment: This is really strange question... Effectively you just have two colums... Should not be a problem @user207421: since a datatable has features this plain html layout has not?

Comment: The problem is that I've a list of object (like Person class, name, email....) how Can I insert its value? As you can see these values are hardcode, not from the DB. The code things about datatable is the pagination, but I can't achieve the same layout.

Comment: You want to hard code dataTable rows into the xhtml instead of receiving data from a bean?

Comment: No, the idea is that the bean has the data from the DB a list of Person. I want to display it with the layout mentioned, but with the possibility of a pagination, like in the Datatable.

Comment: Did you try the p:dataList?

Comment: It could be a good starting point! I'll try it soon!

Comment: Any progress to report?

Comment: I've implemented a trick to show only the first 5 elements, whereas I can search in all the database. So for now I use the repeat mechanism